# React Native new Architecture problem with Codegen

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Im with react native 0.71.0 new Architecture but facing the issue with Codegen :

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native:ReactAndroid:buildCodegenCLI'.

> A problem occurred starting process 'command '.../node_modules/@react-native/codegen/scripts/oss/build.sh''

Here is my settings.gradle file

```
rootProject.name = 'XXX'
   include ':app'
```

```
includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin')
if (settings.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && settings.newArchEnabled == "true") {
    include(":ReactAndroid")
    project(":ReactAndroid").projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid')
    include(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine")
    project(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine").projectDir = file('../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/hermes-engine')
}
includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native') {
dependencySubstitution {
         substitute(module("com.facebook.react:react-android")).using(project(":ReactAndroid"))
         substitute(module("com.facebook.react:react-native")).using(project(":ReactAndroid"))
         substitute(module("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")).using(project(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine"))
         substitute(module("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine")).using(project(":ReactAndroid:hermes-engine"))
        //  substitute(module("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")).using(project(":"))
     }
 }
include ':@react-native-community_datetimepicker'
project(':@react-native-community_datetimepicker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker/android')
include ':@react-native-community_datetimepicker'
project(':@react-native-community_datetimepicker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker/android')
include ':react-native-firebase'
project(':react-native-firebase').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/android')
include ':react-native-device-info'
project(':react-native-device-info').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-device-info/android')
include ':react-native-device-info'
project(':react-native-device-info').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-device-info/android')
include ':rn-fetch-blob'
project(':rn-fetch-blob').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/android')
include ':react-native-is-device-locked'
project(':react-native-is-device-locked').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-is-device-locked/android')
include ':react-native-otp-verify'
project(':react-native-otp-verify').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-otp-verify/android')
include ':react-native-otp-verify'
project(':react-native-otp-verify').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-otp-verify/android')

// apply from: '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy'
// includeUnimodulesProjects()
apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../scripts/autolinking.gradle");
useExpoModules()

// apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle");
apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

include ':app'

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../scripts/autolinking.gradle")
useExpoModules()
```

Changed newArchEnabled=true in gradle.properties

Added  "react-native-codegen": "^0.71.5" under devDependencies in package.json

Here is my app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
import com.android.build.OutputFile
react {
}


project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,
    entryFile: "index.js",
    bundleInDebug: true,
    bundleInRelease: false,
    cliPath: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/cli.js",
    hermesCommand: '../../node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermesc/%OS-BIN%/hermesc',
    composeSourceMapsPath: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/scripts/compose-source-maps.js",
]

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../react.gradle")

project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf', 'Ionicons.ttf' ] 
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false


def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false


def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'


def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", true);
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim());
                configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'xxx.xxx.xxx'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.0.2"
    }

    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

      applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
      
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/*.so'
        pickFirst '**/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/libfbjni.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/your_name.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/your_name.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/your_name.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/your_name.so'
    }
     ndkVersion '24.0.8215888'

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
    }

dependencies {
     // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
       
    def isGifEnabled = (findProperty('expo.gif.enabled') ?: "") == "true";
    def isWebpEnabled = (findProperty('expo.webp.enabled') ?: "") == "true";
    def isWebpAnimatedEnabled = (findProperty('expo.webp.animated') ?: "") == "true";

    if (isGifEnabled || isWebpEnabled) {
        implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
        implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:2.0.0'
    }

    if (isGifEnabled) {
        // For animated gif support
        implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'
    }

    if (isWebpEnabled) {
        // For webp support
        implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:2.0.0'
        if (isWebpAnimatedEnabled) {
            // Animated webp support
            implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:2.0.0'
        }
    }

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-safetynet:16.1.2'
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:0.185.0") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:0.185.0") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.182.0") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }
    
    if (enableHermes) {
        debugImplementation files(new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('hermes-engine/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../android/hermes-debug.aar"))
        releaseImplementation files(new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('hermes-engine/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../android/hermes-release.aar"))
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.api
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Not able to proceed further with the build due to the error. Any update on the same would be highly appreciated.

Comment: which system you have? Mac, Windows

Comment: I have Macbook Pro

Comment: In case of M1 chip I hoe you are running as Rossetta

Comment: Not running M1 chip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by removing Codegen, expo upgrade and adding it again. It's strange, but it did the job! Thanks, @Iva

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing permission to run the command.

- Open the terminal
- Make sure you have command line tool select, In case it is missing
  command `xcode-select --install`
- to fix the permission issue run `chmod +x node_modules/@react-native/codegen/scripts/oss/build.sh`

I hope this will help

Comment: The file seems missing here. I am getting :

chmod: node_modules/@react-native/codegen/scripts/oss/build.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: try installing node_modules again yarn install or npm install, Whatever you are using

Comment: I Did it already

Comment: The only solution I think of is to create build.sh manually bt copying it from react native git repo

Comment: Did not help either. Getting the same issue even after copying build.sh

Comment: after copying you need to give permission as per above code